# How to fetch records using JPQL with case insensitive match

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, toplink

I am trying to fetch the records of employees using JPQL but I don't know name with exact case.

```
select e from Employee e where e.name = 'rahul'
```

what changes I need to make in above JPQL to get the list of employee whose name is Rahul, rahul or RAHUL etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to fetch the records, though not sure if this is efficient one or not.

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e where lower(e.name) = :name", Employee.class);
query.setParameter("name", name.toLowerCase());
query.getResultList();
```